# Concat values into new column in mySQL

Tags: mysql

Here's the pseudo-code I'm trying to do:

```
update msa_list_copy 
select group_concat(distinct msa_name separator ', ') as concat_msa_name
group by msa
```

My table `msa_list_copy` has two columns...msa and msa_name. I'm trying to concatenate msa_names that share the same msa (number) and save this value in a (currently empty) third column `concat_msa_name, but I can't quite get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the field you are updating.

```
update msa_list_copy join 
(select msa, group_concat(distinct msa_name separator ', ') 
      as concat_msa_name from msa_list_copy
   group by msa) as t0 using(msa) 
set msa_list_copy.concat_msa_name=t0.concat_msa_name
```

Comment: This gives me an SQL syntax error at line 1 starting at the first parentheses

Comment: Fixed. I was using your group by query and it was missing the table name.

Comment: Tried this and it ran with no errors, but it didn't actually update my table. `concat_msa_name` is all null

Comment: Sorry! Disregard! That worked. My table didn't refresh. Thanks!

Comment: This leaves me with rows with duplicate content for the new concat column. Is there a simple way to delete rows with the same content in two columns (msa and concat_msa_name)?

Comment: Use a where clause in your delete command: delete * from msa_list_copy where msa_name=concat_msa_name

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is:

```
update msa_list_copy inner join  
(select group_concat(distinct msa_name separator ', ') as concat_msa_name
group by msa) as q on msa_list_copy.concat_msa_name=q.concat_msa_name set msa_list_copy.concat_msa_name = q.concat_msa_name
```

Comment: it should specify the join in the update to say which record gets updated.